# snake game: snake colliding with itself

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I am currently writing a snake game code and I am nearly finished however I am having difficulty writing a code which will cause the game to end if the head of the snake collides with its body, I thought I could create a collide function similar to the collide function for the snake and the apple:

```
pygame.sprite.collide_rect(h, a)
```

however all the separate parts of the snake act in the same way so the snake will always be constantly colliding with itself. Are there any ways around this.

here is my full snake code:

```
import pygame
import random


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 250, 0)
RED = (250, 0, 0)
Width = 15
Space = 3
Xspeed = 18
Yspeed = 0
Factor = 18
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
segments = 2
HitLoop = 0
ScreenWidth = 800
AppleCount = 1

#creating initial snake
class HEAD(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, colour = GREEN):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([Width, Width])
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class APPLE(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, z, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([Width, Width])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = z
        self.rect.y = q

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([ScreenWidth, ScreenWidth])
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()


SnakeSegments = []
for i in range(segments):
    x = 250 - (Width + Space) * i
    y = 30
    h = HEAD(x, y)
    SnakeSegments.append(h)
    allspriteslist.add(h)

AppleList = []
for i in range(0,AppleCount):
    z = random.randint(10,ScreenWidth-25)
    q = random.randint(10,ScreenWidth-25)
    a = APPLE(z, q)
    AppleList.append(a)
    allspriteslist.add(a)

#main loop
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if Xspeed == -Factor:
                    Xspeed = 0
                if Xspeed == Factor:
                    Xspeed = Factor
                else:
                    Xspeed = Xspeed - Factor
                    Yspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if Xspeed == Factor:
                    Xspeed = 0
                if Xspeed == -Factor:
                    Xspeed = -Factor
                else:
                    Xspeed = Xspeed + Factor
                    Yspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if Yspeed == -Factor:
                    Yspeed = 0
                if Yspeed == Factor:
                    Yspeed = Factor
                else:
                    Yspeed = Yspeed - Factor
                    Xspeed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if Yspeed == Factor:
                    Yspeed = 0
                if Yspeed == -Factor:
                    Yspeed = -Factor
                else:
                    Yspeed = Yspeed + Factor
                    Xspeed = 0
    clock.tick(10)
    #snake builder
    OldSegment = SnakeSegments.pop(-1)
    allspriteslist.remove(OldSegment)

    x = SnakeSegments[0].rect.x + Xspeed
    y = SnakeSegments[0].rect.y + Yspeed

    h = HEAD(x, y)
    SnakeSegments.insert(0, h)
    allspriteslist.add(h,a)
    allspriteslist.update()

    # collision had to create apples own list for respawn
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(h, a) == True and HitLoop == 0:
        SnakeSegments.append(h)
        AppleList.append(a)
        HitLoop = HitLoop + 1
        z = random.randint(10, ScreenWidth - 25)
        q = random.randint(10, ScreenWidth - 25)
        OldApple = AppleList.pop()
        allspriteslist.remove(OldApple)
        a = APPLE(z, q)
        allspriteslist.update()

# collision had to create a new class
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(h, h) == True:
        pass


    # hit timer
    if HitLoop > 0:
        HitLoop += 1
    if HitLoop > 4:
        HitLoop = 0

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    #game walls
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, 0, ScreenWidth, 10])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, 0, 10, ScreenWidth])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [0, ScreenWidth - 10, ScreenWidth, 10])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [ScreenWidth - 10, 0, 10, ScreenWidth])
    if x <= 10:
        done = True
    if x >= ScreenWidth - Width:
        done = True
    if y <= 10:
        done = True
    if y >= ScreenWidth - Width:
        done = True


    allspriteslist.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please dont add random content to get around editor restrictions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snake colliding with itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972082/snake-colliding-with-itself)

Comment: It is, indeed, the same question, word by word; with a slightly different title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code it looks as though you are checking if the head of the snake collide with itself, which will always return True. You need to individually check that the head of snake does not collide with any of it's trailing segments:

```
for segment in SnakeSegments[2:]:
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(h, segment):
        pass # collision detected, game-over
```

The head of the snake is expected to collide with the segment directly behind it, which is why we need to start with the 3rd element in the list.

Comment: westgarthw this is a huge help thank you, however this also returns as true if the snake eats the apple as well?