# Problem with snake colliding with itself (snake game)

Tags: java, swing, timer, keypress, paintcomponent

I've got this problem with my snake game, it runs into itself when you for example are going left and press up and right fast, because i only told the game that i can't press right if it's going left, and therefor if I press up right before i press right it allows me to which makes the snake go into itself.

So when you run the program just press Next and press space and the game should start then when you are going left just press up and right quickly after that and see it for yourself. I'm not sure how to fix this unfortunatly since we've only learned Java for like 6 months and we only really learned the basics like if etc. If you have any questions I am answering quick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [snake game: snake colliding with itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987900/snake-game-snake-colliding-with-itself)

Comment: @fantaghirocco No, not the same cause of the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: @fantaghirocco I'm not sure if you are trolling or sincerely confused, but the answer you provided is 1) written in another language and 2) is not the same problem the OP has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code which now make it work correctly as you would expect.

Essentially the problem was that if 2 keys are pressed fast enough before the timer ticks and `snakeMove` gets called, you would overwrite the `direction` variable and thus a key will be "missed".

So imagine these steps take place:

1. `direction` is *V*, the snake is going to the left
2. Timer ticks and `snakeMove` is called, the method evaluates `direction` which is *V* so snake continues to move to the left
3. Before the timer ticks again I press *up* + *right* at the "same time". Thus 2 events take place before the timer ticks again:

   1. 1st key is processed so `direction` is set to *up* `direction == "U"`
   2. 2nd key is processed so `direction` is set to *right* `direction == "H"`
4. Now only the timer ticks again and `snakeMove` is called. The method evaluates `direction` in a switch statement and `direction == "H"`, thus we have "missed" the `direction == "U"`as it was overwritten by the second key press in `keyPressed` method the before the timer ticked

To overcome this as I suggested in your previous question to use a FIFO (first in first out) list to correctly process all keys so they are never "missed".

This can be done using a [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which has the `pop()` function we need.

So in your code I renamed the global variable `direction` to `currentDirection`:

```
private String currentDirection;
```

and removed the `static` modifier as this is not needed, I also removed the `static` modifier on `snakeMove` as again this is not needed and stops us from accessing instance variables i.e. `currentDirection`. I also changed the scope to `private` as in the snippet you showed it was unnecessary for it to be `public`, but these changes are just for more correctness of code. I then created a global variable:

```
private LinkedList<String> directions = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then everywhere (except in the `snakeMove` method) I removed `currentDirection =`  and replaced it with `directions.add(...)`, thus we are no longer changing a single variable, but rather adding each direction to our *FIFO*/`LinkedList`. I also removed some if checks you did in the `keyPressed` as this was not needed, even if the snake is going in the same direction as the key that is pressed - who cares, just add it to the list of keys pressed so we can process it later in `snakeMove`

Then in your `snakeMove` I did this:

```
public void snakeMove() {
    ...

    if (!directions.isEmpty()) { // if its not empty we have a new key(s) to process
        // proccess the keys pressed from the oldest to the newest and set the new direction
        currentDirection = directions.pop(); // takes the first oldest key from the queue
    }

    switch (currentDirection) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and that solves the problem mentioned above.

Here is the code with these changes implemented:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class FirstGraphic extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    //Storlek på fönstret
    static int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 840;

    Timer tmMove = new Timer(150, this);

    private JFrame window;

    static int bodySize = 40, xNormalFruit = 0, yNormalFruit = 0, gameSquares = (WIDTH * HEIGHT) / bodySize,
            snakeParts = 7, score = 0, restartButtonWIDTH = 190, restartButtonHEIGHT = 50;

    static int x[] = new int[gameSquares];
    static int y[] = new int[gameSquares];

    private String currentDirection;
    boolean gameRunning = false, gameStarted = false, instructions = false, isDead = false;

    public static JButton restartButton = new JButton("STARTA OM"), toInstructionsButton = new JButton("Nästa");

    private LinkedList<String> directions = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Snake Game");
        FirstGraphic content = new FirstGraphic(window);
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        restartButton.setBounds((WIDTH / 2) - (restartButtonWIDTH) / 2, (HEIGHT - 40) / 2 + 100, restartButtonWIDTH, restartButtonHEIGHT);
        restartButton.setBackground(new Color(48, 165, 55));
        restartButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        content.setUp();
    }

    public FirstGraphic(JFrame window) {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void setUp() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        restartButton.addActionListener(this);
        directions.add("H");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (gameRunning) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, (HEIGHT - 40));
            g.setColor(new Color(63, 116, 41, 255));
            g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 40, WIDTH, (2));
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 240));
            g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - 38, WIDTH, 38);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        }
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (gameRunning) {
            g.setColor(new Color(35, 179, 52, 223));
            g.fillOval(xNormalFruit, yNormalFruit, bodySize, bodySize);
            g.setColor(new Color(44, 141, 23, 255));
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            for (int i = 0; i < snakeParts; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillOval(x[i], y[i], bodySize, bodySize);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                    g.fillOval(x[i], y[i], bodySize, bodySize);
                }
            }
        } else if (!gameRunning && gameStarted) {
            gameOver(g);
        } else if (!instructions) {
            startScene(g);
        } else {
            instructions(g);
        }
    }

    public void startScene(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 85));
        g.drawString("Ormen Olle's", 150, 170);
        g.drawString("Äventyr", 235, 254);
        window.add(toInstructionsButton);
        toInstructionsButton.setBounds(240, 660, 300, 100);
        toInstructionsButton.setBackground(new Color(48, 165, 55));
        toInstructionsButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        toInstructionsButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 60));
        toInstructionsButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void instructions(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 85));
        g.setColor(new Color(14, 69, 114));
        g.drawString("PRESS SPACE", 210, 720);

    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 65));
        FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Du dog!", (WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth("Du dog!")) / 2, (HEIGHT - 40) / 2);
        g.setColor(new Color(44, 141, 23, 255));
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        FontMetrics metrics2 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("SCORE: " + score, (WIDTH - metrics2.stringWidth("SCORE:  " + score)) / 2, 50);
        window.add(restartButton);
    }

    public void checkFruit() {
        if ((x[0] == xNormalFruit) && (y[0] == yNormalFruit)) {
            snakeParts++;
            score++;
            newFruit();
        }
        for (int v = 1; v < snakeParts; v++) {
            if ((x[v] == xNormalFruit) && y[v] == yNormalFruit) {
                newFruit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {
        for (int i = snakeParts; i > 0; i--) {
            if ((x[0] == x[i]) && (y[0] == y[i])) {
                gameRunning = false;
                isDead = true;
            }
        }
        if (x[0] < 0) {
            gameRunning = false;
            isDead = true;
        }
        if (x[0] == WIDTH) {
            gameRunning = false;
            isDead = true;
        }
        if (y[0] < 0) {
            gameRunning = false;
            isDead = true;
        }
        if (y[0] > (HEIGHT - 40) - bodySize) {
            gameRunning = false;
            isDead = true;
        }
        if (!gameRunning) {
            tmMove.stop();
        }
    }

    public void snakeMove() {
        for (int i = snakeParts; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }

        if (!directions.isEmpty()) {
            currentDirection = directions.pop();
        }

        switch (currentDirection) {
            case "H":
                x[0] = x[0] + bodySize;
                break;
            case "V":
                x[0] = x[0] - bodySize;
                break;
            case "U":
                y[0] = y[0] - bodySize;
                break;
            case "N":
                y[0] = y[0] + bodySize;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void newFruit() {
        xNormalFruit = (rollDice(WIDTH / bodySize) * bodySize) - bodySize;
        yNormalFruit = (rollDice((HEIGHT - 40) / bodySize) * bodySize) - bodySize;
    }

    public static int rollDice(int numberOfSides) {
        //Kastar en tärning med ett specifikt antal sidor.
        return (int) (Math.random() * numberOfSides + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (actionEvent.getSource() == restartButton && isDead) {
            isDead = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < snakeParts; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    x[i] = 0;
                    y[i] = 0;
                } else {
                    x[i] = 0 - bodySize;
                    y[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            gameRunning = true;
            tmMove.start();
            //direction = "H";
            directions.clear();
            directions.add("H");
            window.remove(restartButton);
            score = 0;
            snakeParts = 7;
            newFruit();
            repaint();
        }
        if (actionEvent.getSource() == toInstructionsButton && !instructions) {
            instructions = true;
            window.remove(toInstructionsButton);
            repaint();
        }
        if (actionEvent.getSource() == tmMove) {
            if (gameRunning) {
                snakeMove();
                checkFruit();
                checkCollisions();
            } else {
                repaint();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !gameRunning && instructions) {
            snakeMove();
            checkFruit();
            checkCollisions();
            newFruit();
            gameRunning = true;
            instructions = false;
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && gameRunning) {
            if (gameStarted) {
                gameStarted = false;
                tmMove.stop();
            } else {
                tmMove.start();
                gameStarted = true;
            }
        }
        if (gameStarted) {
            switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                    directions.add("H");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                    directions.add("V");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                    directions.add("U");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                    directions.add("N");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_E:
                    tmMove.setDelay(200);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_M:
                    tmMove.setDelay(150);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_H:
                    tmMove.setDelay(100);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    }
}
```

Some other notes to name a few are:

1. All swing components should be created on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`
2. Dont use `setBounds` or `setSize`, use an appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and call `JFrame#pack()` after all components are added and before making it visible
3. Override `getPreferredSize` as opposed to calling `setPreferredSize`
4. You don't need to use graphics to do simple stuff like drawing a string, simply use a `JLabel` and add it to a `JPanel` with an appropriate layout
5. You can cast your `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2D` object and some [anti-aliasing and other rendering hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html) to your drawing so it looks sharper
6. You should use [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a `KeyListener`
7. Separate your codes concerns, don't use one `actionPerformed` for all purposes such as timer and buttons callbacks, use anyomous classes to make the code more clean and concise

Comment: Damn, this was really useful, I will make sure to check it out when i get home from school. Really appreciated!

Comment: I tried this out, and it worked exactly as I wanted it to except one small thing. It's just that if I hold down left arrow for example it spams V in the queue and it breaks, but couldn't i fix that with a if statement to see if the queue contains the key pressed?

Comment: I'm just wondering how it works. Like how does the list get cleared everytime?

Comment: Glad to help. Yeah you could maybe check if the last key added is equal to the current key being pressed via `directions.getLast().equals(...)`. The queue gets cleared in 2 ways 1. by calling [LinkedList#pop()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop--) in the `snakeMove` method. Popping an item off the queue removes it aswell and 2. using [LinkedList#clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#clear--) when the game is restarted.

Comment: Don't feel you stole anything, you asked a question with the code all there just not working in a certain edge case and got an answer, you never expected the work to be done for you, you showed code to correctly illustrate the problem. Deleting the code will kind of void this question and render it not as useful to others. And anyway anyone can click on the edits of your question or my answer and see all edits made. You will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the right solution though?

If someone turns too fast, say when travelling left, do an 'up' and 'right' too fast, snake is still on the same y-axis, since its hasn't changed yet with up movement, and with a 'right' key press, snake is trying to move on x-axis while y-axis value is still the same.

I captured x and y values in your program and they look like this for a normal run at the first turn to down. After start, I let the snake run all the way to the right wall and turn just down before it hit the wall:

```
x[0],y[0] | x[1],y[1]
720 , 0   | 680, 0     <-- coordinates before turn
720 , 40  | 720, 0     <-- coordinates after turn
```

For this one, after start, I let the snake run to the wall and then did a fast turn to down + right, causing a game over, coordinates look like this:

```
x[0],y[0] | x[1],y[1]
720 , 0   | 680, 0     <-- coordinates before turn
680 , 0   | 720, 0     <-- coordinates after down + right turn
```

The behavior to me looks like what it should be, unless I've missed something. If you want to avoid this, try adding a small fraction of delay after a keypress.

Comment: Yeah, that seems more like it but how should I make it so that you're able to press down and right fast and it prioritezes the down and after that's been made it triggers the right? I thought something like this: Make a if statement, if you press up and right while going left etc. first turn up then turn right. And do this with all possible places this can happen. But I'm not sure how to make it so I can detect if I press two keys with a small delay between them.